# how to parse dd.mm.yyyy format RegularExpressionAttribute MVC'sDataAnnotations?

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, data-annotations

i want to create DateTimeAttribute like that:

```
   public class DateTimeAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
    {
        public DateTimeAttribute(): base(@"\d\d.\d\d.\d\d\d\d")
        {

        }

    }
```

i want to make my format: dd.mm.yyyy it is too simple but: 

**^((((0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]).-/.-/)|((0?[1-9]|[12]\d|30).-/.-/)|((0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])[.-/]0?2.-/)|(29[.-/]0?2.-/))|(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(0[13578]|1[02])((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)(0[13456789]|1[012])((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])02((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|(2902((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)|00))))$**

it is too diffucult also not working? how to parse dd.mm.yyyy in my regex expression?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? "it's not validating at all", "it accepts illegal values", "it rejects legal values", something else? Details please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\.](0[1-9]|1[012])[\.](19|20)[0-9]{2}
```

But this will match invalid dates like February 31st. So you'll need to check validity of the date anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use the built in attribute?

```
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date in the format dd.mm.yyyy")]
```